# What does this statsmodels output mean?

Tags: python, statistics, time-series, forecasting, arima

I'm trying to forecast a univariate time series variable with exogenous factors using statsmodels SARIMAX. I'm trying to analysis the time series with the seasonal_decompose function and this is the output I'm getting:

[image]

What does it mean when the seasonal output is just this big block?

### Edit

Decomposition for 1 month
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like seasonal component has relatively high frequency, for example weekly or day of week, so it's not a block but very frequent line chart with points between -0.05 and 0.05.

Try to plot for example only one month of data to look more closely.

UPDATE:

As You can see on the second chart of June there are 4 peaks, which suggest seasonality is per day of week.
You can judge if this make sense if You have domain knowledge about data.

Comment: So that means there is a high seasonal component in this time series, right?

Comment: You need to inspect the data first. I suspect very frequent seasons, but to proof detailed chart may be needed - 1 month of data for example.

Comment: updated the post with decomposition for month of june @ipj